# Entering recovery mode when plugging powered off tablet to charger

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, recovery-mode, charging, clockworkmod-recovery

I installed Philz Touch 6.59.0 (ClockworkMod 6.0.5.1) in my Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 7" Wifi (SM-T230) and modified the `/system/bin/lpm` (also called playlpm in other devices) to reboot the device as soon as it is plugged.

The modification of the `lpm` file works great when I don't have Philz Touch 6.59.0 installed on the device. Every time the device is off and I plugged it to the charger, it starts Android just fine.

The problem comes when I install Philz Touch 6.59.0 which works great by it self but when I modify the `lpm` file, every time **I power off the device and then plug it to the charger, it start in recovery mode which is incredibly anoying**.

Next is my lpm file:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
/system/bin/reboot
```

Does anyone knows what can I do to solve this issue or change this behaviour?

**EDIT**

I also tried the TWRP and the same thing happens. When powered off and plugged in, the device starts in recovery mode.

Comment: I've no clue about this issue, although it makes me think about the **jig** device, which is a little electric circuit used to force the Download mode in a powered off device. Its mechanism is simple: it limits the voltage to a value which is interpreted as the value which triggers the booting in Download mode. I guess that the CWM modified some parameter in such a way that the voltage value in input triggers the Recovery, instead of the OS, but I've zero proof of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simply a problem of line endings. Somewhere along the road I modified the `lpm` file and the line endings of the file were changed to Windows and they were supposed to be to Unix line endings.

When you edit a file in a text editor make sure to the correct line endings. Next is a picture of how to do it in Sublime Text:

[image]